# Match character only if not first in line and other character not in same line

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match a character, say `=`, only if

1. it's not at the beginning of a line and
2. another character, say `$`, does not appear on the same line?

For clarification, in

```
$a = b
a
= b
a = b
```

I only want to match the equal sign in the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will do the job

```
/^[^$]+=[^$]+$/
```

This matches 1 or more non `$` sign, an equal sign and 1 or more non `$` sign

```js
var test = [
    '$a = b',
    'a',
    '= b',
    'a = b',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^[^$]+=[^$]+$/.test(a);
}));
```